# What resolution(s) should photos be to be shown on iPhone?

Tags: mobile, user-expectation

I have an app where users have profile photos.

Profile photos will be shown frequently, and are about 3/4 the size of a regular iPhone.

Of course, the tradeoff is bigger resolution means higher quality but also more data and higher cost.

I am building a pipeline to generate thumbnails of appropriate sizes after they are uploaded.

What sizes should they be for a good user experience?

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to display a crisp image on all iPhone sizes. In order to do so, create (or convert) your design to the largest iPhone screen size - which is currently the iPhone XS Max, at 2688 x 1242px. The exact dimensions of the profile picture at that screen size, is the maximum at which the image can be displayed. Using those exact dimensions for the cropped profile picture, will ensure a crisp image on all iPhone screen sizes.

The same method can be applied to apps that are intended for both Android and iOS - as long as you work with the biggest screen that your design will be displayed on.

Additionally, when it comes to development, clever compression can be applied to the cropped image to decrease its file size (similar to tweaking export settings when saving an image in Photoshop). This usually entails quite a bit of effort, and you'll have to gauge whether the value added (a smaller app using less data) is worth the added development time and complexity.